# Bootstrap Pills In JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Morning,

Not very good at web and hence appreciate any helping hands on my following issue.

Here I am using Bootstrap pills instead of tab to show switch-able view. This work in a web page and does show pages upon click on each pill.

Please check this.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<div id="Div1">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="active"><a href="#contactUs" data-toggle="tab">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#applyOnline" data-toggle="tab">Apply Online</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="contactUs">
      <h2>
                    contact us</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="applyOnline">
      <h2>
                    apply online</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the challenge start when I tried to load above content using JQuery Dialog. 
I.e, I able to see my model dialog pops up, render pills and first page. But nothing happens when I click on the pills to switch view.

Please check this.

```js
function ShowContactUs() {
            $(function () {
                $("#contactUsContainer").dialog({
                    create: function () { $(this).parent().appendTo('form') },
                    modal: true, width: 500,

                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+400' },
                    title: "Contact Us/Complete Online"
                    
                }
                      );

            });

        };
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" /> 



<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowContactUs()" >Show</button>

<div id="contactUsContainer" class="ui-helper-hidden">
        <div id="Div1">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#contactUs" data-toggle="tab">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#applyOnline" data-toggle="tab">Apply Online</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="contactUs">
                <h2>
                    contact us</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="applyOnline">
                <h2>
                    apply online</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone advise me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what impact it made to the JQuery Dialog when removing following line (highlighted in block) from the script. However, removing that line solved the issue. If someone knows more about it then please feel free to comment.

```
    function ShowContactUs() {
                $(function () {
                    $("#contactUsContainer").dialog({
                        create: function () 
{
```

> $(this).parent().appendTo('form')

```
},
                        modal: true, width: 500,

                        position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+400' },
                        title: "Contact Us/Complete Online"

                    }
                          );

                });

            };
```

Comment: What that line of code was doing was appending your dialog box to any `form`element on your webpage, you weren't targetting an specific element, thats why when you had multiple `form`elements it breaks as it duplicates HTML markup on all of them.

Comment: Then when triggering tab actions, there were duplicate elements with the same ID, so tabbing action was being executed on other elements that weren't visible at the moment

Comment: This could be easily fixed by targeting the append action to an specific form by assigning and ID and targetting it like `$(this).parent().appendTo('#your-form-id')`. This way you could have multiple form elements and just append it to the form you really want to, so no HTML markup is being duplicated and tabs will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing happens when I click on the pills to switch view.

Because you have a same content in tabs.

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="contactUs">
            <h2>
                contact us</h2> // Here..
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="applyOnline">
            <h2>
                contact us</h2> // And Here..
        </div>
</div>
```

Nevermind it may happen with anyone, Thanks..

---

```js
function ShowContactUs() {
            $(function () {
                $("#contactUsContainer").dialog({
                    create: function () { $(this).parent().appendTo('form') },
                    modal: true, width: 500,

                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+400' },
                    title: "Contact Us/Complete Online"
                    
                }
                      );

            });

        };
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" /> 



<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowContactUs()" >Show</button>

<div id="contactUsContainer" class="ui-helper-hidden">
        <div id="Div1">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#contactUs" data-toggle="tab">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#applyOnline" data-toggle="tab">Apply Online</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="contactUs">
                <h2>
                    Contact Us</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="applyOnline">
                <h2>
                    Apply Online</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. However, it still doesn't work in my webpage. But it works in my original post and your post.

Comment: @Nair Also it works on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/yrstwzyx/), have you runs another scripts in your page may conflict with it, Thanks?

Comment: Yes. I do have other script. However, to prove the point, I removed all other script for the purpose of proving the point. But no change and still it isn't switching the pages.

Comment: No. Thanks. However, I guess the issue might be due to multiple FORM tag. So I removed all Form tag other than one and it started behaving as expected. However, I am still not sure about what cause this issue since multiple forms are allowed within a single page.

Answer (score 0):

As OP stated on his comments, he had multiple `<form>` elements on his HTML markup, so when jQuery Dialog was being executed, it had this instruction:

```
create: function () { $(this).parent().appendTo('form') },
```

Then this takes al HTML from the dialog box and appends them to *all* form elements present on the DOM. So this creates duplicate dialog boxes, with the same ID values. There shouldn't be duplicated ID values on the DOM.

Then tabs won't work because Bootstrap tab plugin works like this, when an anchor `<a>` element have the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute, it will get the value of `href="#contactUs"` for getting the ID of the `<div>` that has the tab content to be shown, as they were duplicated on the previous script the behavior isn't as expected because its intended to be only one tab-content div with that ID to trigger the tab show action.

To fix this assign an ID to the `<form>` element where you want to include the dialog box (example) `<form id="my-desired-form">` on your HTML.

Then change the Javascript to

```
create: function () { $(this).parent().appendTo('#my-desired-form') },
```